# Can I upload large images to my server through an HTML form without using RAM?

Tags: django, memory, upload, image-uploading

I am building a site that requires the user to upload images that will be around 70MB each to my server.  Currently I am running a Linode with 512MB of RAM.  There isn't much extra memory to spare due to other sites being on this server, so is it possible to upload those images to the server without taking up any RAM by dumping the image directly to the filesystem, or does any file uploaded via POST have to be loaded into memory first before it can be dumped to the filesystem?  Does the nature of this problem require a server with a lot of RAM?

Would there be a way to somehow integrate an ftp client into an html form?  I'm using Django if that makes a difference.

Comment: Technically it is possible by uploading parts of file in several requests and appending them into the same file. With HTML5 you can use `FileAPI`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your project settings, set FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE to something small (eg 1024 bytes). That will make Django spool request.FILES to disk sooner, not use up RAM

Docs are here if you want more detail: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#file-upload-max-memory-size

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement .... django files upload have two types of uploading.

1 - InMemory Upload
2. Temporary Upload

In case of InMemoryUpload the files you uploaded is in ram only through request.FILES ,
But can set that upload to covert it from InMemoryUpload to TemporaryUpload which ultimately use /tmp folder to store it .. which saves for RAM ...

In settings.py :-

**FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE** = #something

The maximum size, in bytes, for files that will be uploaded into memory. 
Files larger than FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE will be streamed to disk.
Defaults to 2.5 megabytes.

**FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR** = #to sme path

The directory where uploaded files larger than FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE will be stored.
Defaults to your system’s standard temporary directory (i.e. /tmp on most Unix-like systems).

Then you can write that file in chunks to your required directory as /tmp deletes all files once system is down.
Follow this link :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#changing-upload-handler-behavior

Comment: Thanks for telling me. Improved , do it need more information ?